# Удалить номер телефона из контакта

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть контакт с несколькими номерами. Как можно удалить отдельный номер из контакта?

Comment: А в чём вопрос? Зайдите через меню и удалите.

Comment: 0xdb, очевидно, MODifikaTOR интересуется, как сделать это программно

Comment: @0xdb я делаю контактную книжку. Это стандартная функция контактной книжки, но я не знаю как её реализовать. Поэтому и пишу сюда.

Answer (score 4):

Для демонстрации я создал новый проект с Basic Activity и на присутствующий в ней FloatingActionButton навешал функцию удаления номера из первого контакта.

Прежде всего, для работы с контактами понадобятся соответствующие разрешения. Добавьте в AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

На API Level выше 23 так же придётся разрешения проверить и запросить:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
                        }, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
                    } else {
                        // Наш будущий метод удаления номера
                        // будет показан дальше
                        removePhoneByNumber(1L, "+7 123 456-78-90");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                removePhoneByNumber(1L, "+7 123 456-78-90");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Не положено!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Данные о контактах хранятся в системной базе данных SQLite. [В документации советуют](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html?hl=ru) изменять в ней данные в пакетном режиме с помощью [ContentResolver.applyBatch()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html?hl=ru#applyBatch(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E)). Последуем совету. Для этого добавим в MainActivity пару констант и сам метод удаления номера:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    private final String queryPhone = Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=? AND "
        + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " AND ";
    private final String queryByNumber = Phone.NUMBER + "=?";

    ...

    public void removePhoneByNumber(Long contactId, String phoneNumber) {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList();
        String[] phoneArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(contactId), phoneNumber};
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(queryPhone + queryByNumber, phoneArgs)
                .build());
        try {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы не столкнуться с прихотями форматирования телефонного номера в базе, константу `queryByNumber` можно немного усложнить:

```
private final String queryByNumber = ""
        + "replace(replace(replace(" + Phone.NUMBER + ", ' ', ''), '-', ''), '+', '')"
        + Phone.NUMBER
        + "=?";
```

И ту же нормализацию применяем к номеру передаваемому в аргументе метода:

```
phoneNumber.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")
```

Comment: Судя по тому, что всплыла старая ошибка, ваш код работает, спасибо. А как заполнить массив ContentProviderOperation? На данный момент у меня все ошибки упираются в него:
    `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.`

Comment: Судя по ошибке у вас в `phoneArgs` меньше двух элементов.

Comment: Вывел значения обоих аргументов `phoneArgs` - они оба заполнены. Добавлял третий, выводил все три - заполнены. Но ошибка та же. Как быть?

Comment: Давайте продолжим [обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57283/).